# I'm confused with the definition of the parameters

Tags: real-analysis, definition

Let $M$ be a manifold and $\varphi:U_0\to U$ be a parametrization. For every $x=\varphi(u)\in U$, although the point $y$ is in $\mathbb R^n$, it needs only $m$ *numbers* to have its position determined, we say, the $m$ coordinates of $x\in U_0$ which we call parameters.

Afterwards the author of the book I'm studying say $\{\frac{\partial \varphi(u)}{\partial u_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial\varphi(u)}{\partial u_m}\}$ is a basis of the tangent vector space $T_xM$.

So I'm a little confused with the notation. In the first paragraph the $u_1,\ldots, u_m$ are *numbers* and $u$ is a fixed point in $U_0$. On the other hand, in the second one they are vectors.

After all, what are they? could anyone give me a more concrete example?

I need help, the author didn't say anything else about this discussion.